# JNA: How to pass a pointer to a local variable?

Tags: java, pointers, jna, local-variables

I have two local variables:

```
Pointer output;
int output_len; /* or better `size_t output_len;` */
```

I need to pass pointers to these variables into (the same named arguments of) a JNA function:

```
    public int libcomcom_run_command(
            byte[] input,
            size_t input_len,
            PointerByReference output,
            Pointer output_len,
            byte[] file,
            PointerByReference argv,
            PointerByReference envp,
            int timeout);
```

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new PointerByReference(pointerValue);
new IntByReference(intValue);
```

You can't actually "take the address" of a local Java variable.  The `XByReference` types allocate memory for the value in question, and then refer to the address of that memory.

After the invocation you can call `XByReference.getValue()` to see any changes to that memory.